# JavaScript: function doesn't work properly with async

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, async-await, quicksort

I am writing a function for quick sort and I want to add a little delay to slow it down a little, but when I make the function async (I don't even add the delay yet) the function seems to stop working after the first partition.

Here's my code

```js
function quickSort(arr, low, high) {
  if(low < high) {
    let pi = quickSort_part(arr, low, high);

    quickSort(arr, low, pi-1);
    quickSort(arr, pi+1, high);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

and here is the `quickSort_part` function. `bars` array in this function is a set of `div` elements I want to animate (and thats why I want to add a delay). When I make this function async, it doesn't work properly

```js
async function quickSort_part(arr, low, high) {
  let pivot = arr[high];
  i = low - 1;

  let bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
  bars[high].style.backgroundColor = "red";

  for(let j = low; j < high; j++) {
    bars[j].style.backgroundColor = "blue";

    if(arr[j] < pivot) {
      i++;
      let temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = temp;
      bars[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      bars[i].style.height = arr[i]*10 + "px";
      bars[j].style.height = arr[j]*10 + "px";
      bars[i].innerText = arr[i];
      bars[j].innerText = arr[j];
    }
    await sleep(100);
  }

  let temp = arr[i+1];
  arr[i+1] = arr[high];
  arr[high] = temp;
  bars[i+1].style.height = arr[i+1]*10 + "px";
  bars[high].style.height = arr[high]*10 + "px";
  bars[i+1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  bars[high].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  bars[i+1].innerText = arr[i+1];
  bars[high].innerText = arr[high];
  return i+1;
}
```

Also, here is the `sleep` function.

```js
function sleep(delayInMS) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delayInMS));
}
```

Can someone help me on what I am doing wrong or whats going wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: `async` functions return a Promise - perhaps you were expecting some other result? in an `async` function, you `await` Promises ... there are no promises in the code ... it's hard to tell you what you did wrong since you haven't posted the code that has the problem

Comment: I made the `quickSort_part` function async and added `await sleep()` after the `if` statement in side the `for` loop. Thats it, but even when I dont add the sleep function, just async then too the function doesnt work properly. I have added those changes now you can look

Comment: as I mentioned in the comment `async` functions return a Promise ... so `pi` in `let pi = quickSort_part(arr, low, high);` is a Promise - try `async function quickSort` and `let pi = await quickSort_part(arr, low, high);` and `await quickSort(arr, low, pi-1);` `await quickSort(arr, pi+1, high);`

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand

Comment: like this https://pastebin.com/vL0JqGxL

Comment: Ohh yeah, sorry silly mistake, thanks. You can make this an answer so that I can upvote it

Comment: Can I suggest that a much cleaner way of doing this is to extend a simple quicksort algorithm to also generate a sequence of *events* handled, including starting a new substep, choosing a partition, and swapping two indices.  Then use that sequence of events for your animation.  This breaks down the responsibility well.

Comment: I want to second what @ScottSauyet said. Just pass an extra argument that is an array that you will modify in place by adding events. Then figure out how to display those events at the desired pace. This separates sort logic from display, making both simpler.